# Gremlin.Net return multi sub vertex in the same array

Tags: c#, gremlin, janusgraph

Usually family contains one father and mother but multi children,
In gremlin I can say to get a family:

`g.V(61464).as('me').outE('father').inV().as('father').select('me').outE('mother').inV().as('mother').select('me').inE('father').outV().as('child').select('father', 'mother', 'child')`

this will return the following:

```
 - ==> *{father=v[16408], mother=v[450608], child=v[139504]}*
 - ==> *{father=v[16408], mother=v[450608], child=v[163880]}*
 - ==> *{father=v[16408], mother=v[450608], child=v[176368]}*
```

but I want to get them in this way:

> ==> {father=v[16408], mother=v[450608], children=[v[139504], v[163880], v[176368]]

Is there any way to do that in gremlin and more specific in Gremlin.Net. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample graph in the form of Gremlin queries that be copied in the Gremlin Console when you ask Gremlin questions. That makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably with the [`project`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.7/reference/#project-step) step:

```
gremlin> g.V(61464).project('father','mother','children').
             by(out('father')).
             by(out('mother')).
             by(__.in('father').fold())
==>[father:v[4344],mother:v[4152],children:[v[8440],v[12536],v[40964200]]]
```

(The ids don't match with yours as I had to create the graph myself and got other ids.)

Note, that the `__` for `__.in('father')` is only necessary for Gremlin-Groovy as `in` is a reserved keyword in Groovy and
`out('father')` is a shorter form of `outE('father').inV()`.

You can write the same traversal in Gremlin.Net. Then it looks like this:

```
g.V(61464).Project<object>("father", "mother", "children").
            By(Out("father")).
            By(Out("mother")).
            By(In("father").Fold()).Next();
```

(You need a `using static Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.__;` to be able to write the traversal like this. Otherwise the `By`-steps would look like this: `By(__.Out("father"))`. See the TinkerPop docs for [more information on this](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.7/reference/#_static_enums_and_methods_2).)

Comment: Thank you very much, It was very helpful :)

Comment: Hi Florian Hockmann when I use this 
g.V(61464).Project<object>("father", "mother", "children").
            By(Out("father")).
            By(Out("mother")).
            By(In("father").Fold()).Next();
if the selected vertex doesn't have a father the query break out, how can i avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best solution here, but one way to solve this is with the [coalesce step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.7/reference/#coalesce-step): `By(Out("father"))` becomes `By(Coalesce<object>(Out("father"), Constant("has no father")))`. `Coalesce` has the effect that the `Constant` step will be executed when `Out("father")` returns no vertices.